# How to get a list of all openssl or libcrypto error codes

Tags: c, error-handling, openssl

How can I get a list of all the Error Codes and Strings for LibCrypto or OpenSSL API that the ERR_ APIs from OpenSSL use (for e.x. [ERR_error_string](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/ERR_error_string.html))? Digging through the source code of libcrypto did not get me anywhere, and neither did any of my web searches.

My end goal is to write tests corresponding to failure scenarios outlined in the error cases.

Comment: At a glance there are some files with the error codes and strings, and then the keys they are given would be referenced in the implementations of the API functions. You're going to have to do some legwork, the error codes reported with `ERR_error_string()` don't seem to be listed in the official docs, although they seem to specify when to check for a code.

Comment: @SkypeMeSM did you get the list ? I also want the list.

Comment: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-errstr.html

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you were searching for this? [openssl.ec](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/err/openssl.ec)
It seems like the error codes are generated by util/mkerr.pl